# C++: Using a Stack to Verify if Parentheses are Balanced (Logic error)

Tags: c++, struct, stack

I have a simple stack I created with basic initialize, show, push, pop, top, etc. functions. I need a function to verify whether or not a string has matching parentheses. I think I'm pretty close, but I have a problem with the following: **if (s.size == 0 && c == ')')** in the middle of my balanced function.

This condition should be met by string "s1" with the parenthesis just prior to the division sign, but it is not...It is still returning true.

Thanks for looking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Stack{
    static const unsigned MAX_SIZE = 5;
    char data[ MAX_SIZE ];
    unsigned size;
};

void initialize( Stack & stack );
void show( const Stack & stack );
unsigned getSize( const Stack & stack );
void push( Stack & stack, char c );
char pop( Stack & stack );
char top( const Stack & stack );
bool die( const string & msg );
bool balanced (const string & expr);

int main(){

    string s1 = "X*((4+(3-2)/(Y+X))+(Z-8))) / ((A+(B-2))";
    string s2 = "())";
    string s3 = "(()";

    cout << balanced(s1) << endl;
    cout << balanced(s2) << endl;
    cout << balanced(s3) << endl;

}

void initialize( Stack & stack ){
    stack.size = 0;
}

void show( const Stack & stack ){
    cout <<"[" << stack.size <<"]:";
    for(  unsigned i = 0;  i < stack.size;  i++  )
        cout <<stack.data[i];
    cout <<endl;
} // show

unsigned getSize( const Stack & stack ) {return stack.size;}

void push( Stack & stack, char c ){
    if( stack.size == Stack::MAX_SIZE )  die( "push: overflow" );
    stack.data[stack.size++] = c;
} // push

char pop( Stack & stack ){
    if( stack.size == 0 )  die( "pop: underflow" );
    return stack.data[--stack.size];
} // pop

char top( const Stack & stack ){
    if( stack.size == 0 )  die( "top: underflow" );
    return stack.data[stack.size-1];
} // top

bool die( const string & msg ){
    cerr <<endl <<"Fatal error: " << msg <<endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

bool balanced (const string & expr){

    Stack s;
    initialize(s);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < expr.size(); i++){
        char c = expr[i];

        if (c == '(')
        {
            if( expr.size() == Stack::MAX_SIZE )  {
                die( "push: overflow" );
            }

            push(s, c);

        }

        if (s.size == 0 && c == ')')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (c == ')'){
            pop(s);
        }

        if (s.size == 0){

            return true;
        }

        else

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks to me like the expression `if (s.size == 0 && c == ')')` is indeed balanced, since the first closed parenthesis is in quotes. does that not matter? Further, it looks like you don't take quotes into account when pushing an open parenthesis character on the stack

Comment: `if (s.size == 0) { return true; }`: This line must not be inside your loop, but rather once you've finished the inspecting each character. Otherwise any string that start with a character other than '(' is immediately considered balanced, and any string that is balanced at any point before the end suffers the same (potentially incorrect) fate.

Comment: GREAT catch, dlev. That was it (I need to be more careful next time) - Thank you!

Comment: You check for stack overflow in push and outside. Better only check in the stack. And if this is C++, why C-style global functions?

Comment: why did you make `die` return a `bool`? That's just useless, as it exits before being able to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer you needed seems to have been provided in the comments of your question (nice catch, dlev), I'd like to suggest an alternative approach, which is probably faster.

```
bool balanced(const string& expression)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (expression[i] == '(') ++count;
        else if (expression[i] == ')') --count;
        if (count < 0) return false;
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

This effectively throws away the stack structure, keeping only its size. Should it ever go below 0, it means an unmatched right parenthesis was found, and if the loop terminates without reaching 0, then there are `count` unmatched left parentheses.

It should also be noted that it would not suffice to check for `count < 0` after the loop has finished, since things like `")("` would pass the test.